# Why setting 'Accept-Time' header manually with timestamp would always have 'undefined' when using XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: request, header, xmlhttprequest

I was trying to send POST request in the console of DevTools by using XMLHttpRequest.
My JavaScript code is as following:

```
var serverTime = Date.now().toString(),
post_data = 'token=......',
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('POST', 'https://......', false);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept-Time', serverTime);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
xhr.send(post_data);
```

The `serverTime` variable is a timestamp string, for example, '1692943302368'.
The setting of header key `Accept-Time` ought to be with '1692943302368'.

However, after running this snippet, the response status code was 403.
I observed the `Request Headers` in DevTools and found the `Accept-Time` was `undefined, 1692943302368` which might lead to failure of the POST request.

Why there's always `undefined` before the timestamp?

[image: Snapshot of the Request Headers after running my code]

On contrary, the original JavaScript code of the website would always set the header field with just the timestamp plainly without `undefined,`.
[image: Snapshot of the Request Headers after running the original JavaScript code of the website]

Unfortunately, since the original JavaScript code of the website had been obfuscated so heavily that I could not find the magic how it set the headers.

I had tried to search articles about this matter but with no relavant result. Is there anything wrong with the setting of headers in my code? How to set the header field Accept-Time properly?

I tried to clear the value of `Accept-Time` by using:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept-Time', '');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept-Time', serverTime);
```

Disapointingly this way will merely assgin `undefined,,1692943302368` for `Accept-Time`.
It seems there's no effective ways to delete the header keys and values.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody answered my question for one week...

I discovered that the `xhr.setRequestHeader()` had been overriden by the obfuscated JavaScript code, that's why the `setRequestHeader()` function would became weird.

Instead of XMLHttpRequest, I turned to another approach to solve this matter by using `fetch`:

```
var url = 'https://......',
page='1',
serverTime=Date.now(),
token='......',
post_data = {'page': page, 'token': token},
formData = new URLSearchParams(post_data),
headers = new Headers();
headers.append('accept', 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01');
headers.append('content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
headers.append('accept-time', serverTime);
headers.append('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: headers,
  body: formData
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => console.log(data))
.catch(error => console.log(data));
```

Finally this code would return satisfactory result.